# PackageReference style package copy files to solution

Tags: nuget

For the old solution-level `packages.config` I have an `init.ps1` script that copies some files from the `tools` directory into the root of the solution:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package)

$rootDir = (Get-Item $installPath).parent.parent.fullname

$filesSource = join-path $installPath 'tools'

Copy-Item "$filesSource/build.cake" $rootDir -Force
Copy-Item "$filesSource/build.ps1" $rootDir -Force
```

The nuspec is simply:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        ... the standard properties ...
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="build.cake" target="tools\build.cake" />
        <file src="build.ps1" target="tools\build.ps1" />
        <file src="nuget\init.ps1" target="tools\init.ps1" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Moving across to the `PackageReference` NuGet 3.0 style, the install path comes out as the system-level package area (c:\users\me\.nuget\packages). This means the script behaves differently.

The aim of the package is to be an internal distribution of our common build scripts (using Cake) to our standard project structure. This allows us to make common changes and have them consumed via a NuGet update across our projects.

I can't find much on the net about how you go about replicating this type of behaviour, just that features are still in development and that there are different ways to tackle the old problems.

So firstly, is this possible? Secondly, if so, how?

<sub>On the upside, it might be an excuse to write a custom `dotnet` tool.</sub>